# vb.net Removing illegal characters - but not whitespaces

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have used Microsofts MSDN example for removing illegal characters from a string (to be used for mysql queries).

However, how can I modify function so that it does not remove space in a string? 
E.g. Input "Test test" will show up as "Testtest"

```
Function CleanInput(strIn As String) As String
    ' Replace invalid characters with empty strings.
    Try
       Return Regex.Replace(strIn, "[^\w\.@-]", "")
    ' if we timeout when replacing invalid characters, we should return String.Empty.
    Catch e As RegexMatchTimeoutException
       Return String.Empty         
    End Try
End Function
```

Any other useful tips are also appreciated

Solution found: Adding a \s to the regex string resolved my issue

```
       Return Regex.Replace(strIn, "[^\w\s\.@-]", "")
```

Comment: Useful tip: don't inject SQL in the first place and this becomes a non-issue.

Comment: What if you need to insert a name like O'Brien into your database?  Won't this code omit the apostrophe?  Why go through this effort?  Just use parameterized queries and you won't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

The actual updated version of that function is as follows:

```
Return Regex.Replace(strIn, "[^\w ]", "")
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: I have figured it out. I should add a \s to the regex expression

Regex.Replace(strIn, "[^\w\s\.@-]", "")